# Browser links opening in app instead of browser due to deep links

Tags: browser, navigation

This is what I am facing right now. I have certain pages configured as Android app links in manifest file of my app. They work as expected when I search for those pages in Google and click on those links resulting in opening the corresponding app pages.
My issue is when I am browsing the same pages on Chrome OS browser on my phone and try to navigate to the same links in the browser itself, they still open the app instead of navigating in the browser itself.

So for example if I have a Android app link in manifest file as scheme://host/path/
When I type this link in browser or open browser with scheme://host and navigate to path, it opens the app instead of keeping the user in the browser itself.
How do I prevent user from opening the app when navigating in the browser itself?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, you might want to try our sister site [so].

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer remaining in browser rather than having corresponding app launched when a link is clicked, try changing settings here(opt out the apps to stop them from being launched)

> Here's how it can be done:

> Navigate to your phone Settings > Apps and look for Default apps.

> Under Default apps settings, tap on the Opening links option.

> On the next page, disable the toggle for Open supported links.

[Source](https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2023/02/20/how-to-stop-google-chrome-from-opening-apps-on-android/?expand_article=1)

Comment: That almost did the trick for me. On the next step I had to instead select my app and add a `verify link`.